# Black hole thermodynamics in a time dependent metric

Tags: quantum-field-theory, general-relativity, gravity, string-theory, black-holes

For a time dependent space time metric, to get the thermodynamics, does the standard procedure of Wick rotating the time, and then calculating the free energy, work ?

Comment: It is not a direct answer, but a black hole which evaporates should correspond to a time dependent metric, while the thermodynamic analogies (temperature, etc...) are still correct. Temperature will have a time dependence.

Comment: Suppose the classical metric itself has time dependence, nothing to do with anything quantum mechanical. For example, replace the $r$ in Schwarzschild metric with $t$ (with the signature changed appropriately). I think the whole procedure of constructing the Kruskal manifold will go through. Then if you Wick rotate the time, you do not get any periodicity in time, and hence the usual way of getting the temperature does not work. Rather since you replaced $t$ with $r$, I think you shall get a periodicity in $r$ if you Wick rotate it.

Comment: @Sourav: Please could you give me the reference from which you are learning black hole thermodynamics?

Comment: @ramanujan_dirac I never learnt it from a single place. I read the paper http://journals.aps.org/prd/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevD.15.2752 by Gibbons and Hawking, which is about this particular method of calculating free energy. I have gone through papers dealing with the thermodynamics of the BTZ black hole.

Answer (score 2):

In principle it should not. The problem with the Wick rotation is that what you are doing is embedding the Lorentzian manifold in a complex manifold of which it is a slice, and then looking for a different slice with Riemannian signature. In general there is no such Riemmanian slice, and even if it does exist it need not be unique.

There is an [old paper from Wald](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/communications-in-mathematical-physics/volume-70/issue-3/On-the-Euclidean-approach-to-quantum-field-theory-in-curved/cmp/1103907345.full) showing that for globally static spacetimes, such as Schwarzschild, everything goes smoothly, there is a unique slice and you can go on.

I'm not familiar with further improvements on this, besides [this paper](https://aip.scitation.org/doi/abs/10.1063/1.528480) which gives necessary conditions for a spacetime to admit the Riemannian counterpart (very strong conditions indeed, the spacetime must posses totally geodesic three dimensional submanifold).

So you see that in general you have no reason to expect the Wick rotation to still work. But it may be the case that one can construct an example of time-evolving black hole that still has the Riemannian section. In any case it will propably not mantain the KMS condition (the periodicity in time of Green's functions) so that there is no well-defined temperature.